# Can we run through tags of examples under Scenario outline?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, gherkin

Can we run through tags of examples under Scenario outline?
I am using cypress+cucumber+typescript.

PFB my feature file code:

```
@run1

Scenario Outline: Doing some tests

  Given a step

  When I do some <input>

  Then I should get some <output>

@daily

Examples:

  |input     |output    |

  |daily 1   |daily 2 o |

@weekly

Examples:

  |input     |output    |

  |week 1    |week 1 o  |

  |week 2    |week 3 o  |
```

I want some command-line command to run only @daily tag. Currently, I am running cypress **run -e TAGS=@run1**, I am looking for something like cypress **run -e TAGS=@daily**

Comment: `run -e TAGS=@daily` should pick only rows from your first example table which is tagged with @dialy. Do you see any issue when you run with `run -e TAGS=@daily`?

Comment: @supputuri I am not able to retrieve rows from first example in cypress gherkin setup